# three.js: multiple color on the same face

Tags: three.js

I have a cube of size 1 x 1 x 2. On the larger (1 x 2) face, I would like to show one color on half of the face, and another color on the other half. What would the recommended way of implementing this? Should I use hierarchy to build this 1 x 1 x 2 cube using two 1 x 1 x 1 cubes of different face color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the pattern to follow. Adjust to your liking:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10, 10, 20, 1, 1, 2 );

for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) {
    geometry.faces[ i ].color.setHSL( Math.random(), 0.5, 0.5 ); // pick your colors
}

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors } ); 

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

If you are using `CanvasRenderer`, you can set `material.overdraw = 0.5` to try to eliminate the diagonal lines. This is not required for `WebGLRenderer`.

three.js r.60

Comment: Sorry about the belated "accept". Have been busy on other stuff.